# Clickable button to move another tab

Tags: html, jquery, tabs

I am creating tab in my page and my reference is this https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_tab_header.asp. It works nicely till I tried to create a button in the tab which directs to another tab upon click. I tried to add button for Tokyo tab into London tab. It directs into that tab but unfortunately directed tab button background does not change and I know why it does not change but I don't have a solution for it. Your help is most appreciated

```js
function openCity(cityName,elmnt,color) {
  var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablink");
  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].style.backgroundColor = "";
  }
  document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
  elmnt.style.backgroundColor = color;

}
// Get the element with id="defaultOpen" and click on it
document.getElementById("defaultOpen").click();
```

```css
body {font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;}

.tablink {
  background-color: #555;
  color: white;
  float: left;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  font-size: 17px;
  width: 25%;
}

.tablink:hover {
  background-color: #777;
}

/* Style the tab content */
.tabcontent {
  color: white;
  display: none;
  padding: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}

#London {background-color:red;}
#Paris {background-color:green;}
#Tokyo {background-color:blue;}
#Oslo {background-color:orange;}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

</head>
<body>

<p>Click on the buttons inside the tabbed menu:</p>

<div id="London" class="tabcontent">
  <h1>London</h1>
  <p>London is the capital city of England.</p>
  <button class="tablink" onclick="openCity('Tokyo', this, 'blue')">Tokyo</button>
</div>

<div id="Paris" class="tabcontent">
  <h1>Paris</h1>
  <p>Paris is the capital of France.</p> 
</div>

<div id="Tokyo" class="tabcontent">
  <h1>Tokyo</h1>
  <p>Tokyo is the capital of Japan.</p>
</div>

<div id="Oslo" class="tabcontent">
  <h1>Oslo</h1>
  <p>Oslo is the capital of Norway.</p>
</div>

<button class="tablink" onclick="openCity('London', this, 'red')" id="defaultOpen">London</button>
<button class="tablink" onclick="openCity('Paris', this, 'green')">Paris</button>
<button class="tablink" onclick="openCity('Tokyo', this, 'blue')">Tokyo</button>
<button class="tablink" onclick="openCity('Oslo', this, 'orange')">Oslo</button>

   
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code work good because your function will change color of button you clicked, so i create another function for internal button.
Example:

```js
function openCity(cityName,elmnt,color) {
  var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablink");
  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].style.backgroundColor = "";
  }
  document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
  elmnt.style.backgroundColor = color;

}
// Get the element with id="defaultOpen" and click on it
document.getElementById("defaultOpen").click();

function openCityInt(el){
    const x = document.getElementsByClassName(el);
    x[0].click();
}
```

```css
body {font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;}

.tablink {
  background-color: #555;
  color: white;
  float: left;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  font-size: 17px;
  width: 25%;
}

.tablink:hover {
  background-color: #777;
}

/* Style the tab content */
.tabcontent {
  color: white;
  display: none;
  padding: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}

#London {background-color:red;}
#Paris {background-color:green;}
#Tokyo {background-color:blue;}
#Oslo {background-color:orange;}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

</head>
<body>

<p>Click on the buttons inside the tabbed menu:</p>

<div id="London" class="tabcontent">
  <h1>London</h1>
  <p>London is the capital city of England.</p>
  <button class="tablink" onclick="openCityInt('tokyo')">Tokyo</button>
</div>

<div id="Paris" class="tabcontent">
  <h1>Paris</h1>
  <p>Paris is the capital of France.</p> 
</div>

<div id="Tokyo" class="tabcontent">
  <h1>Tokyo</h1>
  <p>Tokyo is the capital of Japan.</p>
</div>

<div id="Oslo" class="tabcontent">
  <h1>Oslo</h1>
  <p>Oslo is the capital of Norway.</p>
</div>

<button class="tablink london" onclick="openCity('London', this, 'red')" id="defaultOpen">London</button>
<button class="tablink paris" onclick="openCity('Paris', this, 'green')">Paris</button>
<button class="tablink tokyo" onclick="openCity('Tokyo', this, 'blue')">Tokyo</button>
<button class="tablink oslo" onclick="openCity('Oslo', this, 'orange')">Oslo</button>

   
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you are the best. Thanks for the quick solution.

Comment: You are welcome, if you want you can flag it as answer :)